# Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined even it's working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this login screen, it's working but it show this warning and I'm worried about it. When I click the headerRight button, I have to logout and go back to Login Screen.

I already tried everything this website has to offer

This is my class

```
class AuthLoadingScreen extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this._loadData();   
    }

    _loadData = async() => {
        const isLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
        console.log(isLoggedIn);
        this.props.navigation.navigate(isLoggedIn == null? 'Login' : 'Home');
    }

    _removeToken = async(navigation) => {
        console.log('test');
        await AsyncStorage.clear();
        navigation.navigate('Login');
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View><ActivityIndicator/></View>
        );
    } 
}
```

And this is where I'm calling _removeToken function

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
    },
    Register: {
        screen: Register,
    },
    Home: {
        screen: TabNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: 'Insta Clone',
            headerLeft: null,
            headerTitleStyle: { 
                textAlign:"center", 
                flex:1 
            },
            headerRight: (
                <Button
                    icon={
                        <Icon
                        name='sign-out'
                        type='octicon'
                        color='black'
                        />
                    }
                    onPress={() => (new AuthLoadingScreen)._removeToken(navigation)} // <--- HERE
                    buttonStyle={ {backgroundColor: 'transparent'} }  
                />
            ),
            headerLeft: (
                <Button
                    icon={
                        <Icon
                        name='info'
                        type='octicon'
                        color='black'
                        />
                    }
                    onPress={() => alert("Created by Matheus Melo")}
                    buttonStyle={ {backgroundColor: 'transparent'} } 
                />
            ),
        })
    },
});
```

Comment: Where is declared the attribute `this.props`?

Comment: @Ele I'm declaring it but it's not showing this warning when I'm calling it in _loadData function

Comment: No, is not.  You only have that `props` as param on the constructor.  You never assigned.

Comment: Probably is missing `this.props = props;` within the constructor, just before of `this._loadData();`.

Comment: Didn't work ://

Comment: I think the error is here: `super()` (in the constructor). It should be `super(props)`. (Let me know if this works and I'll post it as an answer - I believe this is the problem but it's not easy to check.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Also didn't work, I can't understand why it works on _loadData but it doesn't in _removeToken

Comment: @MatheusMelo apologies, I'd only read part of the code in the question. I see you're manually constructing an instance of `AuthLoadingScreen`. I'm not sure that you're ever supposed to do this in React (although I'm no React expert!), the idea is that the components get instantiated automatically when you include one in the output of a `render` method. But it's clear why the warning is coming - `new AuthLoadingScreen` isn't passing any props (which I believe is an object passed as an argument to the constructor), so `this.props` is indeed going to be `undefined`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond how to I pass the props, do you know?

Comment: As I said, I think they have to be passed as an object (the keys are the prop names, the values are the corresponding values). But I would be strongly tempted to reconsider your design, instantiating a React component other than in another component's `render` method (or through `ReactDOM.render` for the global component) seems very strange to me. If you are using that method as a general utility, consider extracting it from the component and making it a separate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly navigate to `Login`, no need to use `AuthLoadingScreen` reference, here's how the updated code should look like:

```
const removeToken = async(navigation) => {
        console.log('test');
        await AsyncStorage.clear();
        navigation.navigate('Login');
    }
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
    },
    Register: {
        screen: Register,
    },
    Home: {
        screen: TabNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: 'Insta Clone',
            headerLeft: null,
            headerTitleStyle: { 
                textAlign:"center", 
                flex:1 
            },
            headerRight: (
                <Button
                    icon={
                        <Icon
                        name='sign-out'
                        type='octicon'
                        color='black'
                        />
                    }
                    onPress={() => removeToken(navigation)}
                    buttonStyle={ {backgroundColor: 'transparent'} }  
                />
            ),
            headerLeft: (
                <Button
                    icon={
                        <Icon
                        name='info'
                        type='octicon'
                        color='black'
                        />
                    }
                    onPress={() => alert("Created by Matheus Melo")}
                    buttonStyle={ {backgroundColor: 'transparent'} } 
                />
            ),
        })
    },
});
```

Comment: I just put removeToken as a const outside the class and it works! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @MatheusMelo Glad it helped. Happy coding 